# Why an SD-card saved app uses phone memory

Tags: applications, sms, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

Lately I had issues with my phone's (Samsung Galaxy Mini GT-S5570) internal memory aw well as with the SMS memory. I deleted all unwanted messages, rooted my phone and used `Link2SD` to move some apps as well as link other ones on my SD card.

Yesterday I installed some apps from Samsung Apps and I am facing a rather weird situation. Note that before the installation I had ~20 MB free phone memory.

All those apps are installed on the SD card(at least that's what Link2SD says). The moment I finished the installation I got the error message that

> my phone's internal memory is nearly full

I used `APPMGR III` to see what is my free memory and I found out that I had only ~5 MB left! I was so surprised!

I decided to delete all the new apps only just to find out that after that I had only ~12MB free!

Why did that happened? I checked to see if any app cached but everything seems OK. I keep having the message about the internal memory as well as the SMS one.

How can I fix that? Where did my free memory go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Link2SD* only moves the app itself to your device's SDCard. App data still go to internal storage (`/data/<package_name>`). For every app you install, the Android system automatically creates this directory – and I don't know of any app that doesn't put at least a few files here.

For details, please take a look at the [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info). It not only explains the different *App2SD* approaches taken (including *Link2SD*), but in "Extended Methods" also holds hints for a possible solution to your problem (*S2E*).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot install `S2E` since it requires 2.3 android and I have 2.2.1. I also tried to install `Data2SD` but my phone's `PlayStore` cannot find it let alone the terrible reviews it has received. Is there something similar to those? I searched the net but I couldn't find something...

Comment: The only other thing I've heard of is *DirectoryBind* – though I have no experience with it. As far as I uderstood, it could be used to have the entire `/data` structure moved to your SDCard. The risky thing about those kind of modifications: Never even dream of unmounting/removing your SDCard then while your device is running (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Isn't there an app that can selectively move data apps? Is there a way to do it manualy? I mean to copy and paste the `/data` sub folders on sdcard? The thing is when I connect my phone to my laptop I can only see the SDcard and not the phone...

Comment: Simply copy-and-paste to SDCard doesn't do any good, as the apps would still look for their data in the original place. As I said, I have no experience with this, and don't even know if DirectoryBind supports Android 2.x. So I have to leave this to others. While you're waiting, try a Google search for it.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Perhaps `Mounts2SD` might do the job. I'll ask a new question for that! Thank's